# how to display animated pictures in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am beginner in windows phone.
as well as i know, the windows phone 7 does not support the .gif images

and i want to show the animated images like [.gif] image in my windows phone application.

**so**, how can we display the animated image in windows phone 7?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.
windows phone 7 does not supported the .gif image.

And for your reference,
please refer this link,

[Display GIF or Animated Images in Windows Phone](http://dotnetternikhil.blogspot.in/2013/07/display-gif-or-animated-images-in.html) i show that animated images in windows phone 7 Application.

I Hope you will get a solution here..

Comment: your Welcome..
you will proceed

Comment: @Lynda, I have just migrated blog from wordpress to blogger. So, now it is available at here - http://dotnetternikhil.blogspot.in/2013/07/display-gif-or-animated-images-in.html. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for updating the link!