# How to do gif-like animation in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone

I am a beginner with Windows Phone. According to my information, Windows Phone 7 does not support .gif images and I want to display animated images like [.gif] image in my Windows Phone application.

So, how can we display animated image in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer my Old Answer which specifies the solution to display the gif kind animation in windows phone 7.

Please Refer this link for the Solution [**Answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782887/how-to-display-animated-pictures-in-windows-phone/18782948#18782948).

For more reference please refer the Articles  [**Here**](http://dotnetternikhil.blogspot.in/2013/07/display-gif-or-animated-images-in.html).

Answer (score 1):

With the use of ImageTools dll you can implement
this is the link to download this tool
http://imagetools.codeplex.com/